# How to extract logic from views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In my app I can search `consumptions` by dates.

I have an active record model `Consumption` which `belongs_to :users` and a model `ConsumptionSearch`.

consumption.rb

```
class Consumption < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end
```

consumption_search.rb

```
class ConsumptionSearch 
    attr_reader :date_from, :date_to

    def initialize(params)
        params ||= {}
        @date_from = parsed_date(params[:date_from],Time.now.beginning_of_month.to_date.to_s)
        @date_to   = parsed_date(params[:date_to], (Date.today + 1).to_s)
    end

    def date_range
        Consumption.where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', @date_from, @date_to)
    end

    private
        def parsed_date(date_string, default)
            Date.parse(date_string)
            rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
            default
        end
end
```

In the `consumptions_controller` in the `index` action I can retrieve the wanted consumptions by date

```
class ConsumptionsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @search = ConsumptionSearch.new(params[:search])
        @consumptions = @search.date_range
        @consumptions = @consumptions.order('created_at ASC').where(user_id: current_user.id)
    end
end
```

consumptions schema may help:

```
  create_table "consumptions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.float "total_price"
    t.float "kilometers"
    t.string "shop"
    t.float "liter_price"
    t.float "total_liters"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.float "difference", default: 0.0
  end
```

So in my `consumptions/view/index.html.erb` I just have to iterate over `@consumptions` to display what I need.

**The question is**: how can I make it more "ruby way", I have too much logic in the view... Where and how should I extract the logic? Thanks

```
<%= price = (@consumptions.map { |c| c.total_price }.sum - @consumptions.last.total_price).round(2) %> 
<%= total_km = (@consumptions.map { |c| c.difference }.sum).round.abs %>
<%= (price / total_km).round(4) %> 
<%= (price / total_km * 100).round(2) %>
```

Comment: Hint: Helper methods or methods on the model that can help compute things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create helper: app/helpers/consumptions_helper.rb

```
module ConsumptionsHelper
 def some_logic
   ...
 end
end
```

and use it in the view

```
<%= some_logic %>
```

Please check RoR doc here
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Helpers.html

Answer (score 1):

Why not add the logic to your `ConsumptionSearch` class? You are already abstracting logic to it. And, you are already accessing it in the view. So, perhaps something like:

```
class ConsumptionSearch 
  attr_reader :date_from, :date_to

    def initialize(params)
      params ||= {}
      @date_from = parsed_date(params[:date_from],Time.now.beginning_of_month.to_date.to_s)
      @date_to   = parsed_date(params[:date_to], (Date.today + 1).to_s)
    end

    def date_range
      Consumption.where('created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', @date_from, @date_to)
    end

    def price
      ...
    end

    def total_km
      ...
    end

    def price_per_km(round_to)
      (price/total_km).round(round_to)
    end

  private

    def parsed_date(date_string, default)
      Date.parse(date_string)
      rescue ArgumentError, TypeError
      default
    end
end
```

And then in view:

```
<%= @consumptions.price %> 
<%= @consumptions.total_km %>
<%= @consumptions.price_per_km(4) %> 
<%= @consumptions.price_per_km(2) %>
```

Personally, `helpers` are not my favorite thing. But, I realize that some people use them regularly and with great success. I'm just odd that way.